# Now() without timezone

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.2

I have a column `added_at` of type `timestamp without time zone`. I want it's default value to be the current date-time but without time zone. The function `now()` returns a timezone as well.

How do I solve that problem?

Comment: Current date-time where? At your desk? At the server? At your user's computer? Date-time without time zone doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @MikeW At the environment where it's run.

Comment: Consider using `with timestamp`, especially if your code is run anywhere where daylight savings is used. Or save the time in UTC, not a local timezone. You can always choose what timezone you want to display the data in.

Comment: @some, is that different from `with timezone`?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamp(0) with time zone` if you don't want sub second precision.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `timestamp with time zone`. It doesn't carry a time zone with it at all. It is just in absolute UTC time, with conversion to/from the local time in the `TimeZone` session variable. Just use `timestamp with time zone`; it's almost always the right choice.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
SELECT now()::timestamp;
```

The cast converts the `timestamptz` returned by `now()` to the corresponding `timestamp` in your time zone - defined by the [`timezone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) setting of the session. That's also how the [standard SQL function `LOCALTIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is implemented in Postgres.

If you don't operate in multiple time zones, that works just fine. Else switch to `timestamptz` for `added_at`. The difference?

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

BTW, this does *exactly* the same, just more noisy and expensive:

```
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE current_setting('timezone');
```

Comment: `select now()::timestamptz;` is a better match

Comment: @DmitriKosolobov: `now()` already returns `timestamptz`, hence `now()::timestamptz` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Is that in any way better than `localtimestamp`?

Comment: `now()::timestamp` might do some casting, but it does not convert from local time zone to UTC for me. But `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';` does the right thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, I don't think so. Not in modern versions any more. Subtle details changed over time. In older versions, `LOCALTIMESTAMP`  was translated to `now()::timestamp` internally. Later it was translated to `('now'::text)::timestamp`. And since Postgres 10, `LOCALTIMESTAMP` seems to be a function in its own right. This also showed (and shows) in the default column name. Either way, the resulting value has always been exactly the same. Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: See related fiddles (it was different, yet, in older versions not available at dbfiddle any more): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0362369a6de25808fe891ce5803671b8
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0362369a6de25808fe891ce5803671b8
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0362369a6de25808fe891ce5803671b8
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0362369a6de25808fe891ce5803671b8

Comment: @ThoPaz: `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` returns the local time for time zone UTC. `LOCALTIMESTAMP` or `now()::timestamp` return the local time for the current `timezone` setting of the session. Two different things! Only happens to return the same while your current session runs with `timezone = 'UTC'`.

Comment: I think this did not answer the question which says "without timezon" and user only wants a DATETIME equivalent in pgsql.

Answer (score 60):

Well you can do something like:

```
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE current_setting('TimeZone');
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris';
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Not sure how that makes any sense for a column "added_at". You almost always want an absolute timestamp (timestamp with time zone) not a floating one.

---

Edit responding to points below:

1. Yes,  should use timestamp with time zone (absolute time) unless you have a good reason not to.
2. The client timezone is given by `SHOW TimeZone` or `current_setting(...)` as shown above.

Do take some time to skim the manuals - they cover all this quite well.

Comment: Probably, yes. 1) Should I change the type of the column to be `timestamp with time zone`? 2) How do I know what's the current timezone of a machine where postgresql is running?

Answer (score 25):

["Current Date/Time"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP deliver values with time zone; LOCALTIME and LOCALTIMESTAMP deliver values without time zone.

Answer (score 5):

**New, and Native Answer in 2020**

In PostgreSQL, **If you only want the current date-time** by calling `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` **without time zone, and fractional digits in the seconds field** which come after the decimal point of the seconds field?

(Tested on PostgreSQL v12.4)

Then use this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;
```

If you define your column's data type as `timestamp` (not as `timestamptz`), then you can store the timestamp without time zone, in that case you **don't neet** to add `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0))
```

In the above function, **0 is passed to get rid of the fractional digits** in the seconds field.

Comment: The ```CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE``` works perfectly, This should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your application doesn't care about timezone, you can use `SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP` for it.

Ex:

```
SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP
-- Result: 2023-01-30 17:43:33.628952
```