# Creating insert function with TIMESTAMP

Tags: postgresql, function, types, casting, postgresql-9.5

I created simple table with a simple function, to insert some logs for the elapsed semester:

```
CREATE TABLE log_elapsedsemester(
sy char(9) NOT NULL,
sem char(1) NOT NULL,
date_recorded TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
recordedby varchar(255)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addelapsedsemester(p_sy char,p_sem char,p_date_recorded 
TIMESTAMP,p_recordedby varchar)
returns void
AS
$$
BEGIN
insert into log_elapsedsemester (sy,sem,date_recorded,recordedby) values 
(p_sy,p_sem,p_date_recorded,p_recordedby);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But evertime I use

```
select addelapsedsemester('2019-2020','1',now(),'sample@gmail.com');
```

I get the error:

> ```
> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

If I use a simple `INSERT` with no function it inserts successfully:

```
insert into log_elapsedsemester(sy,sem,date_recorded,recordedby) values ('2020- 
2021','1',now(),'sample@gmail.com');
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 with pgadmin III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to `timestamp` explicitly. Like:

```
SELECT addelapsedsemester('2019-2020', '1', now()::timestamp,'sample@gmail.com');
```

Or use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `now()::timestamp` (equivalent).

The function `now()` returns type `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`), while your function takes `timestamp without time zone` (`timestamp`). The `now()` function produces a *typed* value (unlike the other untyped literals), where Postgres is more hesitant to coerce it to a different type. [Function type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) does not succeed.

The same type coercion still works for the bare `INSERT` command because ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)):

> If the expression for any column is not of the correct data type, automatic type conversion will be attempted.

Be aware that the cast from `timestamptz` to `timestamp` depends on the current `timezone` setting of the session. You may want to be more explicit. Like `now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'`. Or use `timestamptz` to begin with. Then your original call without cast just works. See:

- [Now() without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812091/now-without-timezone/20814972#20814972)

Also, you most probably do not want to use the type <strike>`char`</strike>, which is misleading short syntax for `character(1)`. Use `text` or `varchar` instead. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

This table definition would make more sense:

```sql
CREATE TABLE log_elapsedsemester(
  sy varchar(9) NOT NULL
, sem integer   NOT NULL
, date_recorded timestamptz NOT NULL
, recordedby text
);
```

Or even:

```
sy integer NOT NULL  -- 2019 can stand for '2019-2020'
```

Function parameters would match the column type.

Comment: Aside, [Postgres 9.5 just reached EOL](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading to a current version.