# Finding all rows that have a date in the current season in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a table of surveys in PostgreSQL. I want to find all the surveys that have been done since the start of the current season.
I have written it this way:

```
WITH foo 
AS (

SELECT 
-- This case will find the date of the first day of this season
-- Year is selected based on the current date. This way we can use the same code next year.
-- ** finding the start of the season.
CASE 
    WHEN EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) >= 1 AND EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) < 4 
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP( EXTRACT('year' FROM NOW())||'-01-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')

    WHEN EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) >= 4 AND EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) < 7
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP( EXTRACT('year' FROM NOW())||'-04-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')

    WHEN EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) >= 7 AND EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) < 9 
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP( EXTRACT('year' FROM NOW())||'-07-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')

    WHEN EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) >= 10 AND EXTRACT('month' FROM NOW()) < 13 
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP( EXTRACT('year' FROM NOW())||'-10-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')

END start_season
)
SELECT *
FROM foo f,
my_table t
WHERE date_survey > start_season
```

This solution works. However, I am searching for a simpler solution if exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider just [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('quarter', date_survey) AS start_timestamp
     , *
FROM   my_table t
WHERE  date_survey >= date_trunc('quarter', now());
```

Notably, both expressions produce the same result (except for the data type, possibly), while the `WHERE` clause is in place.

```
date_trunc('quarter', date_survey)
date_trunc('quarter', now())
```

But you might want to use the same query for the whole year or something. Then the added `date_trunc('quarter', date_survey)` is meaningfully different:

```
...
WHERE  date_survey >= date_trunc('year', now());
```

Or maybe add `EXTRACT('quarter' FROM date_survey) AS start_season` to add the quarter number.

Be aware of corner case pitfalls with type `timestamp` (or `date`) depending on the current time zone setting (as opposed to `timestamptz`).

See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- [Now() without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812091/now-without-timezone/20814972#20814972)